# Order by with nulls at the end

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to order by a column in array. Except if the column has null value then place always at the end.

The following code does work and appends null values at the end but it does the same with 0 values whereas in my case 0 is a value.

```
function orderByWithNullsAtEnd(pArray: any[], pAttr: string, pReverse: boolean) {
  const partition = _.partition(pArray, (x) => !!_.get(x, pAttr, null));
  return _.concat(_.orderBy(partition[0], pAttr, (pReverse ? 'desc' : 'asc')), partition[1]);
}
```

I need to always place nulls at the end and not 0s.

Comment: Try replacing `!!_.get` with `null !== _.get`

Comment: I suggest giving input of the function to this question and give the expected output.

Comment: @georg that worked thank you.